# me sale en amarillo una linea y al hacer un cambio en el código y guardarlo no se efectúa el cambio en la pagina (estoy usando flask)

Tags: python, flask

estoy recién comenzando a utilizar flask, seguí unos pasos que vi en varias partes pero me sale este error, que no me permite realizar los cambios a la pagina; ya que cuando sale esta linea en amarillo y efectuo un cambio en el código, lo guardo y luego veo la pagina, el cambio no se ha efectuado.

adjunto foto del error y mi codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Comment: No pones cuál es el error (la captura de pantalla se corta justo cuando iba a mostrarlo). No obstante me aventuro a pensar que se trata de que "el puerto 3000 ya está siendo usado" y ello se debería a que tienes una versión previa del servidor en ejecución. Eso explicaría que "al ver la página sigue igual" (en vez de que al ver la página te da un error porque el servidor está apagado). Veo también que parece que lo lanzas desde VSCode, usando el depurador o el botón "Run". Mejor lo lanzas desde una terminal, y lo matas con Ctrl+C antes de lanzarlo de nuevo.

Comment: @abulafia ese es realmente el error amigo:(, no me aparece nada mas en el cuadro, mira: (edite la publicacion)

Comment: Posiblemente el IDE te está cortando el error completo. Parece que estás usando algún tipo de depurador que te marca de otro color la línea en que ocurrió la excepcion y parte del mensaje. Insisto en que mejor lo lanzas desde una terminal para ver el error completo.

Comment: @abulafia haciendo lo que tu me aconsejaste (lo de "matar" con Ctrl+C y luego lanzarlo con la terminal), me sirvió. Ahora lo que hago es matarlo con Ctrl+C, aplicar los cambios y luego volver a lanzarlo desde la terminal (en la terminal escribo, python App.py, supongo que esa es la manera de lanzarlo desde la terminal), y de esa manera se aplican bien los cambios. muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: De hecho, debido a que tienes `debug=True`, es posible que ni siquiera necesites "matarlo" con Ctrl-C, y que solo por guardar una nueva versión en disco desde el editor, el que está en ejecución lo pille automáticamente. Solo si la versión que guardas tiene algún error que genere excepciones por la terminal puede ser conveniente matarlo y relanzarlo (una vez corregido el error, claro).

Comment: @abulafia sip, tienes razon, muchas graciaaaas amigo!!